# Import GPX to QGIS with WGS84

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gpx

When loading a GPX-File in QGIS it is not referenced on WSG84. It´s shown with wrong coordinates. Settings are WSG84.

Answer (score 4):

GPX files are always WGS84, unprojected - so the issue may be the other files you've loaded. Check:

1. Confirm that your **other** layers have correctly identified CRS
   information: right-click and "Set layer CRS";
2. Under project properties, select 'enable on-the-fly CRS transformation', and select WGS84 (EPSG:4236) as the project CRS;
3. Add your GPX layer. You may be asked for its CRS, or you can select it afterwards (as in step 1) - make sure it's WGS 84.

If you don't have any other layers loaded, just follow step 3 with the single GPX file.

Comment: Also, what version of Qgis are you on? Failing all that, open your gpx file in a text editor and check it looks okay.

Comment: Under Settings / Options, you can choose the default CRS for new Layers. It should be EPSG:4326 for GPX Layers, which have no own CRS information.